# How implement the login and logout functionality by using play 1.2.7 java framework

Tags: java, session, playframework, playframework-1.x

I Am using play 1.2.7 to create login and logout functionality, when user login i will create the session for him,by using session object, my problem is once i done logout that will redirect to the login page but when user click browser back button the page will get refreshed and again that will login

This is my code code when login the user.

```
public static void login() throws Throwable {
        Http.Cookie remember = request.cookies.get("rememberme");
        if(remember != null) {
            int firstIndex = remember.value.indexOf("-");
            int lastIndex = remember.value.lastIndexOf("-");
            if (lastIndex > firstIndex) {
                String sign = remember.value.substring(0, firstIndex);
                String restOfCookie = remember.value.substring(firstIndex + 1);
                String username = remember.value.substring(firstIndex + 1, lastIndex);
                String time = remember.value.substring(lastIndex + 1);
                Date expirationDate = new Date(Long.parseLong(time)); // surround with try/catch?
                Date now = new Date();
                if (expirationDate == null || expirationDate.before(now)) {
                    logout();
                }
                if(Crypto.sign(restOfCookie).equals(sign)) {
                    session.put("username", username);
                    redirectToOriginalURL();
                }
            }
        }
        flash.keep("url");
        render();
    }
```

And this is my logout code when user is logout :

```
 public static void logout() throws Throwable {
        Security.invoke("onDisconnect");
        session.clear();
        response.removeCookie("rememberme");
        Security.invoke("onDisconnected");
        flash.success("secure.logout");
        login();
    }
```

Please save me from this issue how to resolve this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using the secure module is the way to go: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/secure.

Just FYI, there are modules that extends secure module and support role based authorization:

- http://www.playframework.com/modules/deadbolt
- https://github.com/greenlaw110/play-aaa (At the moment the model support mongoDB only, but it's not difficult to implement your sql version)
  ** There is a demo app for play-aaa: https://github.com/greenlaw110/play-aaa-demo/tree/greenl

Comment: Thanks for responding.I will try it now.I will get back you with my feed back.

Comment: It looks to me your code comes from the secure module. Are you using it already?